# Transfer from Terminal 3 to Terminal 1 in Rome Fiumicino

Tags: transit, airports, italy, rome

I am flying from London to Palermo and transferring in Rome Fiumincino. The ticket is for a both flights with the same airline - there is no hold luggage.

1. Will I be able to use the duty free shops in Terminal 3?
2. Do I need to undergo passport control at T3?

From what I read online - the airport is small, but I still need to leave T3 to go to T1 - is this correct?

Comment: What airport are you describing as "small?" Fiumicino FCO had >43M passengers in 2019, and is hardly a small facility.

Comment: I am just repeating what I read. Allegedly, it takes 5 mins to get to t1 from t3.

Comment: Please state your entire itinerary and specify the airports: London, and Rome, and Palermo each has multiple airports. Also please identify the air carrier and your country of citizenship.

Comment: I cannot answer that because the place underwent major remodeling in the last couple of years, and because of the pandemic things changed frantically. Just be aware that you may receive answers not “up to date” if someone wasn’t there very recently.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica looks like there is only one airport in Palermo: [Falcone Borsellino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcone_Borsellino_Airport), but London and Rome do have multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transfer was very fast - it took about 10-15 mins. I have not really figured out how this airport worked. The shops in T1 were accessible but T3 were not during this transfer.